# Как получить найбольшее значение при foreach

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

На сервере получаю список файлов. Из них получаю максимальное количество игроков и количество игроков которые сейчас играют. Так вот мне нужно получить из этих файлов наибольшее значение количества игроков которые сейчас играют. Спасибо
Вот код. Там на функциях все

```
foreach ($this->pg->arenas as $var)
{
    $maxplayer = $var->getSlot();
    $players = $var->getSlot(true);
    $ev->getPlayer()->sendMessage($var->getWorld().": ".$maxplayer."/".$players);
}
```

Comment: С чем возникли трудности?

Comment: А где код, который показывает, как вы получаете количество игроков которые играют?

Comment: С сравнением...

Answer (score 1):

```
$maxplayers = -1;
foreach ($this->pg->arenas as $var)
{
    $maxplayer = $var->getSlot();
    $players = $var->getSlot(true);
    if ($players > $maxplayers)
        $maxplayers = $players;
    $ev->getPlayer()->sendMessage($var->getWorld().": ".$maxplayer."/".$players);
}
echo $maxplayers;
```

Comment: мне нужно не максимальное значение количества игроков а наибольшее значение переменной $players

Comment: @AnonimAnonim Т.е. самостоятельно вы модифицировать приведенный код не можете? Хорошо, сделаю это за вас